# CSRF synctoken vs origin,referreal url

Tags: csrf

Given that origin, referrer and host headers cannot be spoofed  by javascript,
is there a strong reason to use synchronizer token pattern over just using origin, referrer and host headers for CSRF prevention on (POST, DELETE, PUT) requests ?

Comment: Browsers are not the only clients that might send requests to your web application. Using certain tools, origin, referrer and host can be whatever the attacker wants.

Comment: But given the csrf usecase, I imagine the hacker primarily relies on the user performing an action through browser/email client (like opening an email with image src pointing to state changing url). So if those are the type of clients that can cause the attack, the sync token also doesn't seem to help much, as those tokens wouldn't be present in email opened through client or for that matter requests coming through an evil website. So my point is, is token doing anything additional that referrer and origin cannot do?